# Xamarin Forms UWP "Access Denied" error when attempting to get files and folders on the C drive

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, permissions, system.io.file

I am trying to execute the following line of code in my Xamarin Forms UWP app.

```
var tobj_DirectoryFiles = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(@"C:\");
```

When the line of code is executed, an exception is thrown as follows:
HResult = -2147024891
Message: Access to the path 'C:\' is denied.
Source: System.IO.FileSystem
Stack Trace:    at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserEntries(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(String path)
   at UniversalCheckInHost.FileSystem.LoadTree(TreeViewNode pobj_Node) in D:\VStudio\2019\Projects\UCI\Dev\UniversalCheckInHost\UniversalCheckInHost\UniversalCheckInHost\PopUps\FileSystem.xaml.cs:line 80

I know it is missing some permission but I cannot figure out what permission it needs.  I could not find any doco on that.  I currently have the following permissions allows for the UWP project:

Internet (Client & Server)
Internet (Client)
Private Networks (Client & Server)
Removable Storage

Any idea what I am missing in the permissions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/fileio-learning-track

Comment: @Jason - that doco appears to be for straight UWP apps, not Xamarin UWP apps.  For example to documentation talks about using Windows.Storage etc. namespaces.  These namespaces cannot be used in a Xamarin app.  Instead you use the System.IO namespace.  I did try adding the following access:  The broadFileSystemAccess capability allows apps to get the same access to the file system as the user who is currently running the app without any additional file-picker style prompts during runtime.  Adding this restricted access made no difference.

Comment: a XF app is bound by the restrictions of the platform (Android, iOS, UWP) it is running on.

Comment: Yes I know that.  However every thing I read about saving / reading files etc. says to use system.io.  I am using system.io and am receiving the error as stated above.  I was looking for what permissions I needed to add to the application in order to have this work.

Comment: You cannot access files outside of your application location using System.IO. It's a known limitation in UWP.

Comment: OK -- Well I am using the FilePicker NuGet package in another part of my application.  I will have to see what they are using to get full access to the filesystem.  Also - as an FYI - the official system.io namespace documentation did not seem to list any suck restriction.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not received any solution to this problem so I am going to start a new question with a broader subject.  If anyone does find a specific solution to this please let me know.  Also check out this question to continue this conversation: 
[Xamarin Forms how to Save a file to a location where it can be copied off of the original device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935478/xamarin-forms-how-to-save-a-file-to-a-location-where-it-can-be-copied-off-of-the)